# Unexpected behavior concatenating string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two strings in C++11 and I am often getting an unexpected behavior.

First, I have a function that converts any type to string :

```
template <class T>
static inline const char * toStr(T arg) {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << arg;
    return (ss.str()).c_str();
}
```

Then, I use this function like this :

```
string measure_name;
for (unsigned long j = 0; j < 1280; j++) {
    measure_name = string("ADC_") + toStr(j);
    cout << measure_name << endl;
}
```

Everything goes well untill I reach a 4 digit number (> 999) :
my variable `measure_name` often equals to "ADC_ADC_"... and it happens randomly. I did some research and found nothing about this strange behavior.

For your information, this issue is fixed if `toStr` returns a `string` and not a `const char *`.

Also, if I try to print the returned value, I never see it equal to "ADC_ADC_", so I believe the real issue comes from the concatenating instruction :

```
string measure_name;
for (unsigned long j = 0; j < 1280; j++) {
    const char* tmp = toStr(j);
    if (!strcmp(toStr(j), "ADC_ADC_"))
        cout << "bug" << endl; //never happens
    measure_name = string("ADC_") + tmp; //problem comes from here
    cout << measure_name << endl;
}
```

I just wanted to understand what I am doing wrong there... I know I am using very old C++ but it should work anyway.

Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here

```
return (ss.str()).c_str();
```

You are returning a pointer to the buffer of a temporary `std::string` (returned from `str()`). The pointer returned from the function is useless for the caller, because the `std::string` it points to is already gone.

A pointer is just a pointer. If you want a string, return a `std::string`. If you want to return a `const char*` then you need to store the string somewhere and manage its lifetime.

`std::string` does mangage the lifetime of a character array, so just do:

```
template <class T>
static inline std::string toStr(T arg) {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << arg;
    return ss.str();
}
```

If someone needs a c-array of `char` they can still call `c_str` (and use it as long as the `std::string` is still alive).

---

Instead of your `toStr` consider to use [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: @tony_merguez which part do you not understand? What confuses you? `c_str` returns a pointer to the character array stored in the `std::string` returned from `str()`. This `std::string` does no longer exist when you try to use that pointer

Comment: I know that `std::string` manages the lifetime, but I would like to understand (if possible) why what I am doing works well for 3 or less digits. (<999). I was expecting that to work well or not work at all but this random behavior confuses me... I deleted my comment because I considered it as a little bit useless but if you have further informations, they are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: @tony_merguez the pointer returned from your `toStr` is dangling. Using it is always wrong. It is undefined behavior. Undefined behavior can appear to work, or not, or do strange things.

Comment: @tony_merguez: One possible explanation for the difference is something called the "Small String Optimization". Many `std::string` implementations internally store small strings and big strings in different ways. It's quite possible that your implementation chose a length of 4 as the cut-off because on that implementation, pointers are 4 bytes.  Your 3 digit string plus the terminating `\0` for `c_str()` would fit exactly. It's still Undefined Behavior, but the symptoms may differ, or the crash can happen at different times.